# Create txt with full paths to files and some additional text

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, paths

I have a bunch of files, in many folders and I wanted to create txt file with full paths to this files and with space and name of the directory they are in. something like:

```
halva/foo/bar/1/something.jpg 1
halva/foo/bar/2/another.jpg 2
halva/foo/bar/2/anotheranother.jpg 2
```

Creating a list of paths is something like

```
find `pwd` -name *.jpg
```

But I don't know how to add space and directory name after the path.
I'm trying to categorize stuff for school project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ find .  -name *.jpg -exec bash -c 'd=${1%/*}; d=${d##*/}; printf "%s %s\n" "$1" "$d"' Out {} \;
./halva/foo/bar/1/something.jpg 1
./halva/foo/bar/2/another.jpg 2
./halva/foo/bar/2/anotheranother.jpg 2
```

For every file found by `find`, we run the bash script `d=${1%/*}; d=${d##*/}; printf "%s %s\n" "$1" "$d"` where the first argument, `$1`, is the file name.

We use *suffix removal*, `d=${1%/*}`, to obtain the directory name from the full file name.  We then use *prefix removal*, `d=${d##*/}`, to remove all but the name of the last directory from `d`.  Lastly, `printf` is used to print the output.

The string `Out` in the above command is not used unless there is an error in the bash command in which case it functions as the effective command name, `$0`.

#### Saving the output to a file

To save the output to a file, we use *redirection*:

```
find .  -name *.jpg -exec bash -c 'd=${1%/*}; d=${d##*/}; printf "%s %s\n" "$1" "$d"' Out {} \; >SchoolProject.txt
```

The `>` symbol redirects stdout to the file name which follows it.

Comment: Great work! He should append ` > SchoolProject.txt` to your command to get his text file though.

Comment: Thanks for quick response :) I got an error while using this command

    find: missing argument to `-exec'

EDIT:
It works like charm! thank You :D

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix OK.  Example with redirection included.

Comment: `missing argument to '-exec'`:  That error happens if the final `\;` is missing from the command.

Comment: @Piteight if the software allows you, don't forget to up-vote John's answer so he gains reputation points within AskUbuntu.

Comment: I tried, it says I must have more than 15 reputation, but its recorded :)
Thank you very much guys!